# Relationship between Ratio of expectation squared vs ratio of squared expection

Tags: expected-value, ratio, convex

I have these pair of numbers
$ (a, b) = (\frac{4}{9}, \frac{1}{9}) $ and $(c, d) = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{6}) $.

Note that - (a, b) are pair of numbers which represent $((E(e_1))^2, (E(e_2))^2) $ and (c, d) are pair for $((E(e_1^2)), (E(e_2^2))) $

Where, E is the expectation.

Clearly, c>a and d>b (by convexity) and another special thing is that a-b = c-d. So, basically pair (c, d) is superior but when I divide $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$, I get $\frac{a}{b}$ > $\frac{c}{d}$. Why is that?

Is there a property which ensure that this will be true always. Ratio of expectation squared is greater than ratio of squared expections?

Please help

Comment: When you swap the roles of $(a,b)$ and swap $(c,d),$ the inequality flips.  There's nothing to learn here.

Comment: your use of $E^2[\cdot]$ is confusing, as that typically indicates $E[E[\cdot]]=E[\cdot]$ and not $(E[\cdot])^2$.